# How to fix subprocess."CalledProcessError Command returned non-zero exit status 1" OpenedX?

Tags: python, internationalization, ubuntu-16.04, platform, openedx

I'm localizing my OpenedX - Ironwood version. And meet an error when I ran the "paver i18n_generate" command.

I've followed the instruction in this link step by step: https://github.com/edx/edx-platform/wiki/Internationalization-and-localization

I referenced many related topics in the google group of OpenedX, but I still haven't solved that.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/bin/i18n_tool", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('edx-i18n-tools==0.4.9', 'console_scripts', 'i18n_tool')()
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/edx_i18n_tools-0.4.9-py2.7.egg/i18n/main.py", line 60, in main
    return module.main()
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/edx_i18n_tools-0.4.9-py2.7.egg/i18n/__init__.py", line 51, in __call__
    return self.run(args)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/edx_i18n_tools-0.4.9-py2.7.egg/i18n/extract.py", line 129, in run
    execute(make_django_cmd, working_directory=configuration.root_dir, stderr=stderr)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/edx_i18n_tools-0.4.9-py2.7.egg/i18n/execute.py", line 21, in execute
    sp.check_call(command, cwd=working_directory, stderr=stderr, shell=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 541, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'django-admin.py makemessages -l en -v0 --ignore="common/static/xmodule/modules/*" --ignore="common/static/xmodule/descriptors/*" --ignore="*/migrations/*" --ignore="*/envs/*" --ignore="node_modules/*" --ignore="conf/*" --ignore="docs/*" --ignore="*/fonts/*" --ignore="*/img/*" --ignore="*/images/*" --ignore="*/sass/*" --ignore="*/css/*" --ignore="common/test/*" --ignore="test_root/*" --ignore="*/terrain/*" --ignore="*/spec/*" --ignore="*/tests/*" --ignore="*/djangoapps/*/features/*" --ignore="lms/static/js/i18n/*" --ignore="cms/static/js/i18n/*" --ignore="src/acid-xblock/*" --ignore="src/code-block-timer/*" --ignore="src/codejail/*" --ignore="src/django-wiki/*" --ignore="src/done-xblock/*" --ignore="src/edx-jsme/*" --ignore="src/parse-rest/*" --ignore="src/pygeoip/*" --ignore="src/pystache-custom/*" --ignore="src/rate-xblock/*" --ignore="src/xblock-google-drive/*" -d django' returned non-zero exit status 1


Captured Task Output:
---------------------

---> pavelib.i18n.i18n_generate
---> pavelib.i18n.i18n_extract
---> pavelib.prereqs.install_prereqs
---> pavelib.i18n.i18n_validate_gettext
i18n_tool extract

Build failed running pavelib.i18n.i18n_generate: Subprocess return code: 1
```

Comment: Did you try running it again? Is the error still there?